# Why didn't j increment in the while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am a beginner programmer who wants to understand this loop question.

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    j = 0
    while j < i:
        print(j, end=" ")
        j += 1
```

For each iteration, I need to print j in my while loop. I don't understand why during the second iteration, j is printed 0 instead of 1. In my thought process, I thought j is incremented by 1 as 0 < 1 in the first iteration. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On each iteration by `i`, `j` is reset to `0`, so it should be `0`, `0 1`, `0 1 2` etc.

Answer (score 2):

look when you do

```
while j <i:
```

this runs until the condition true so in second iteration the condition will be 1<1 which is false so it goes back and starts again where the value of j is initialized 0.
to neglect it you can write

```
j=0
for i in range(1,5):   
     while j<i
     print(j)
     j+=1
```

Comment: need help with [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Answer (score 1):

your code j = 0 resets j to 0 each time you step outside your while loop back to your for loop.

```
for i in range(1, 5):        # main loop
    j = 0                   # set j to 0
    while j < i:             # first loop 0 < 1    second loop 1 < 1 this jumps 
                                                  # back to main loop and resets 
                                                  # j to 0 so then second print 
                                                  # results in a new instance 
                                                  # of 0 < 2
                                                  
    print(j, end=" ")    # print 0 
    j += 1                 j + 1
```

Comment: If you notice this is why each iteration of your loops your output keeps printing 0's instead of 0,1,2,3,4